# Hide a mark based on a condition

Tags: vega-lite

I'm wondering if it's possible to show just one of the marks based on a condition or something that is fed by a parameter dynamically.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "data": {"url": "data/stocks.csv"},
  "layer": [
    {
      "mark": "line",
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"field": "date", "type": "temporal"},
        "y": {"field": "price", "type": "quantitative"},
        "color": {"field": "symbol", "type": "nominal"}
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": "rule",
      "encoding": {
        "y": {"field": "price", "aggregate": "mean"},
        "size": {"value": 2},
        "color": {"field": "symbol"}
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to create a parameter where a user is able to select one of the two values "line" or "rule." Based on the selection one of the two marks is shown, and the other is hidden.

The data does not change.

Comment: Yes, this is possible. Can you provide a working spec with data and then clarify what your expected result will be. What will drive the visibility of the marks?

Comment: Hey @DavidBacci I just added a working spec. The visibility is driven by the selection by the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go.

[image]

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "data": {"url": "data/stocks.csv"},
  "params": [
    {
      "name": "choice",
      "value": "rule",
      "bind": {"input": "radio", "options": ["rule", "line"]}
    }
  ],
  "layer": [
    {
      "mark": "line",
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"field": "date", "type": "temporal"},
        "y": {"field": "price", "type": "quantitative"},
        "color": {"field": "symbol", "type": "nominal"},
        "opacity": {
          "condition": {"test": "choice == 'rule'", "value": 0},
          "value": 1
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": "rule",
      "encoding": {
        "y": {"field": "price", "aggregate": "mean"},
        "size": {"value": 2},
        "color": {"field": "symbol"},
        "opacity": {
          "condition": {"test": "choice == 'line'", "value": 0},
          "value": 1
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: This is cool! I was not even thinking about the opacity property. Thank you very much.

Comment: can you help me with this question as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75794777/hide-a-mark-based-on-a-condition-follow-up
Please excuse I wasn't precise enough with my requirement in th first question.