# Hide a mark based on a condition - follow up

Tags: vega-lite

This is a follow up question to this question: [Hide a mark based on a condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75793625/hide-a-mark-based-on-a-condition)

I wasn't precise with my requirement, I'm sorry for that.

I want the user to select either a or b, hence the parameter. Only the first mark should be visible if the user selects a. If the user selects b, only the second mark should be visible.
So it's not enough to change the opacity of the bars. I also want only the corresponding x-axis labels to be used instead of A ... D and I ... III.
I only want the labels A .. D for the first bar chart.

Both marks use different columns for the x-axis and also different values.

Here is a working spec:

```
{
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"a": "A", "b": "I", "va": 28, "vb": 1},
      {"a": "C", "b": "I", "va": 43, "vb": 2},
      {"a": "D", "b": "II", "va": 91, "vb": 3}, 
      {"a": "E", "b": "III", "va": 81, "vb": 4}
    ]
  },
  "params": [
    {
      "name": "choice",
      "value": "a",
      "bind": {"input": "radio", "options": ["a", "b"]}
    }
  ],
  "layer": [
    {
      "mark": "bar",
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"field": "a", "type": "nominal"},
        "y": {"field": "va", "type": "quantitative"},
        "color": {"field": "symbol", "type": "nominal"}
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": "bar",
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"field": "b", "type": "nominal"},
        "y": {"field": "vb", "type": "quantitative"},
        "color": {"field": "symbol", "type": "nominal"}
      }
    }
  ]
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an alternative in case you want another option.

```
{
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"a": "A", "b": "I", "va": 28, "vb": 1},
      {"a": "C", "b": "I", "va": 43, "vb": 2},
      {"a": "D", "b": "II", "va": 91, "vb": 3},
      {"a": "E", "b": "III", "va": 81, "vb": 4}
    ]
  },
  "params": [
    {
      "name": "choice",
      "value": "a",
      "bind": {"input": "radio", "options": ["a", "b"]}
    }
  ],
  "transform": [
    {"calculate": "['a', 'b']", "as": "i"},
    {"calculate": "[datum.a, datum.b]", "as": "j"},
    {"calculate": "[datum.va, datum.vb]", "as": "k"},
    {"flatten": ["i", "j", "k"]},
    {"filter": "datum.i == choice"}
  ],
  "mark": "bar",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "j", "type": "nominal", "axis": {"title": "category"}},
    "y": {"field": "k", "type": "quantitative", "axis": {"title": "value"}},
    "color": {"field": "j", "type": "nominal", "legend": {"title": "category"}}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As your data is the same grain, and depends on a parameter to select the combination of category and value, you could attempt using calculate transforms to select the correct columns based on `choice`, e.g.

```
{
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"a": "A", "b": "I", "va": 28, "vb": 1},
      {"a": "C", "b": "I", "va": 43, "vb": 2},
      {"a": "D", "b": "II", "va": 91, "vb": 3},
      {"a": "E", "b": "III", "va": 81, "vb": 4}
    ]
  },
  "params": [
    {
      "name": "choice",
      "value": "a",
      "bind": {"input": "radio", "options": ["a", "b"]}
    }
  ],
  "transform": [
    {"calculate": "datum[choice]", "as": "category"},
    {"calculate": "datum['v' + choice]", "as": "value"}
  ],
  "mark": "bar",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"type": "nominal", "field": "category"},
    "y": {"type": "quantitative", "field": "value"}
  }
}
```

In the `calculate` transform, we're just using accessors based on the value of `choice` to assign the values to more generically named columns that our downstream encodings can use more easily, without the need for multiple layers.

As a result, the dataset looks like this after the transforms if we choose `a`:

| a | b | va | vb | category | value | value_start | value_end |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| "A" | "I" | 28 | 1 | "A" | 28 | 0 | 28 |
| "C" | "I" | 43 | 2 | "C" | 43 | 0 | 43 |
| "D" | "II" | 91 | 3 | "D" | 91 | 0 | 91 |
| "E" | "III" | 81 | 4 | "E" | 81 | 0 | 81 |

...and for `b`:

| a | b | va | vb | category | value | value_start | value_end |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| "A" | "I" | 28 | 1 | "I" | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| "C" | "I" | 43 | 2 | "I" | 2 | 1 | 3 |
| "D" | "II" | 91 | 3 | "II" | 3 | 0 | 3 |
| "E" | "III" | 81 | 4 | "III" | 4 | 0 | 4 |

Here's our corresponding output for `a`:

[image: bar chart for choice 'a']

...and for `b`:

[image]

Hopefully this is what you're looking to achieve.

Comment: Good to see you on SO Daniel. Good solution - have an upvote.